# Call a function in component from service in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this function in Typescript ***(userLogin.service.ts)***

```
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: function (result) {
            var accessToken = result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();

            /* Use the idToken for Logins Map when Federating User Pools with identity pools or when passing through an Authorization Header to an API Gateway Authorizer */
            var idToken = result.idToken.jwtToken;
        },

        onFailure: function(err) {
            alert(err);
        },
        totpRequired: function(secretCode) {
          var code = prompt('Please input the TOTP code.', '');
          cognitoUser.sendMFACode(code, this, 'SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA');
      },


});
```

When it prompts for a otp, i need to call a function which is available in a component, say ***mfaFunciton()*** in ***login.component.ts*** which pops up a modal window to enter the mfa code. Once i click on the verify button on the modal window, i need to collect the code & pass it back to the ***totpRequired*** funciton, & then call `cognitoUser.sendMFACode(code, this, 'SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA');`

Comment: Your modal is dynamicaly created if you use ngx-bootstrap ou material. I think it's a better way. Otherwise, have to add an rxjs subject into this service to launch your modal in the component and add the following of your totpRequired function into an other method that can be called from your component.

Comment: if u don't mind, can u provide some reference on how to achieve the task with ngx-bootstrap.

Comment: Here is how your totpRequired will looks like:
`this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(ModalContentComponent);
this.modalRef.onHide.subscribe((code: string) => {
    cognitoUser.sendMFACode(code, this, 'SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA');
});`

Comment: The documentation is really well done : https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals